# Consultar validade com duas datas usando ef 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Tenho a seguinte model:

```
public class Documento
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int ClienteId {get;set;}
   public int TipoDocumentoId {get;set;}
   public DateTime Emissao {get;set;}
   public DateTime ProximaEmissao {get;set;}
}
```

e armazeno os documentos de um determinado cliente, informando a data de emissão e quando será a próxima data que ele deve emitir novamente (`ProximaEmissao`).

Um exemplo em dados:

```
Id  -  ClienteId   TipoDocumentoId      Emissão       -   ProximaEmissao
1   -  1           -    1            -  12/12/2017     -     12/12/2018
2   -  1           -    1            -  12/12/2018     -     12/12/2019
```

Quero buscar os documentos do cliente `Id = 1` que tem vencido para o ano de `2018` (`01/01/2018 à 12/12/2018`), na tabela acima não pode retornar nenhum. Veja tem uma próxima data em 2018 `Id = 1` mas ele já foi lá e fez `Id = 2`, então não pode vir como vencido.

Meu código atual é este:

```
 db.Documentos
     .AsNoTracking()
     .Where(x => x.Type == model.Type &&
                 DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ProximaEmissao) >= model.Inicio &&
                 DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.ProximaEmissao) <= model.Fim)
     .ToList();
```

A condição é que `DataEmissao` não contenha a data passada, mas a `ProximaEmissao` contenha a data passada.

Comment: @Maniero o que precisa ficar claro? Poderiam me instruir?

Comment: Dizer o que fez e qual é o problema que está tendo já seria um bom começo. Fora isso, ler o *link* ali mostrado pode ajudar também.

Comment: Realizei a atualização, ficou mais claro?

Comment: @Maniero acredito que com o comentário final ficou mais claro, poderia abrir novamente a pergunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.Documentos
    .GroupBy(o => new 
    { 
        o.ClientId, 
        o.TipoDocumentId 
    }
    .Select(o => new
    {
        o.Key.ClientId,
        o.Key.TipoDocumentId,
        Data = o.Max(d => d.ProximaEmissao)
    }
    .Where(o => o.Data >= @dataInicial && o.Data <= @dataFinal)
    .ToArray();
```

Tente isso. Substitua @dataInicial e @dataFinal pelas respectivas datas.